# Div not visible in Bootstrap Carousel (mobile view)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

- **UPDATE!!! See below!!!**

UPDATE: I have discovered the problem but still don't know how to solve it.

So, I have the same problem as before; I have 2 major divs (desktopDiv and mobileDiv) and in them I have 3 divs (Stream, IDE, Chat) for my sections.

When I added iframe video in the Stream div on desktop view AND in mobile view, my mobile view was blank. But if I comment out the iframe in the desktop view, the section becomes visible in the mobile view!
When I add a slack chat to desktop view AND mobile view, my mobile view is blank (still have a problem with this one)...and now I have the same problem with my IDE section!

Since I don't use the same divs for both desktop and mobile, I guess the conflict ends up there because of my structure...like Bootstrap is haveing conflicts because of copies. But how do I solve it??

(check my fiddle below and you can see my construction)

*** ---------- Old question below ----------- ***

I'm trying to have a div show up inside Bootstrap's carousel in mobile view but it's blank. The background color (yellow) I added in its div for dev. purposes is visible but not the content itself.

Here is the added syntax:

```
<div tabindex="3" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 desktopIDE" id="desktopIDE">
    <div class="textAreaDiv" id="textAreaDiv">
      <textarea class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 textArea" id="code" style="display:none">
        conf io as button
          pin = 0

        conf io as led
          pin = 1;

        task read_button on button
      </textarea>
      <div id="editor"></div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- desktopIDE -->
```

This is the div/view on a desktop, which is the wanted behavior:

[image: IDE desktop]

But on mobile dev mode in Chrome, I see this:
[image: IDE mobile]

But you can see that when I press the button "IDE" (or swipe) and as the div slides into place, the correct background color is showing up for a millisecond, just to disappear the next:

[image]

I'm sure I've gone wrong in my css somewhere...
I've put HTML and CSS in a jsfiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/kcw406hc/

P.S. Worth noting is that I don't use the same div on both desktop view and mobile due to specific wanted behavior of divs.

Comment: Provides your css code.

Comment: There is a lot of css that affects in different areas so instead of writing everything here, I added all my css in the jsfiddle link. BUt if it's still not good, let me know and I'll take some time on the side to add it all here :)

Comment: It's better ...If you provides the demo code...you will get proper answer.

Comment: You mean a fully functional demo? Is there any other site where I can do that? In jsfiddle I can't get the same behavior as on my screen due to libs, imgs, mobile view etc.

Comment: UPDATED problem above